# Getting the last clicked HTML Bookmark

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to get the last clicked html bookmark via javascript/jquery?

Below is html:

```
<a href="#div1">div1</a>
<a href="#div2">div2</a>
```

and DIV1 is below:

```
<div id="div1">
    DIV 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, solet nostrud concludaturque no eam. Ne quod recteque pri. Porro nulla zril mei eu. Eu nibh rebum pri, eu est maiorum menandri, ridens tamquam abhorreant te eum. Ipsum definiebas ad mel.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, solet nostrud concludaturque no eam. Ne quod recteque pri. Porro nulla zril mei eu. Eu nibh rebum pri, eu est maiorum menandri, ridens tamquam abhorreant te eum. Ipsum definiebas ad mel.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, solet nostrud concludaturque no eam. Ne quod recteque pri. Porro nulla zril mei eu. Eu nibh rebum pri, eu est maiorum menandri, ridens tamquam abhorreant te eum. Ipsum definiebas ad mel.
<div>
```

and DIV1 is below:

```
<div id="div2">
    DIV 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, solet nostrud concludaturque no eam. Ne quod recteque pri. Porro nulla zril mei eu. Eu nibh rebum pri, eu est maiorum menandri, ridens tamquam abhorreant te eum. Ipsum definiebas ad mel.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, solet nostrud concludaturque no eam. Ne quod recteque pri. Porro nulla zril mei eu. Eu nibh rebum pri, eu est maiorum menandri, ridens tamquam abhorreant te eum. Ipsum definiebas ad mel.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, solet nostrud concludaturque no eam. Ne quod recteque pri. Porro nulla zril mei eu. Eu nibh rebum pri, eu est maiorum menandri, ridens tamquam abhorreant te eum. Ipsum definiebas ad mel.
<div>
```

[jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/TuEqL/)

I would like to have a javascript function that I can call that tells me if I clicked on a bookmark, and which bookmark was actually clicked.

Comment: Bookmark? Do you mean you want to have a function that tells you if you clicked on one of the two links at the top of the page?

Comment: Simple. Get the value of location.hash, then select the element that has that as it's href. I think your fiddle is missing javascript.

Comment: location.hash is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much Kevin B.

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TuEqL/1/)***

```
$('a').click(function () {
    alert("You clicked" + this.href); // Will give you the full link
});
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/TuEqL/4/)***

```
alert("You clicked " + this.href.split('#')[1]); //Will give just the div id
```

Comment: although your answer was not exactly was not what I was looking for, I felt that it was legitimate...  Not sure why you got a downvote...

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of identifier to find in your method. I just used your HTML contents of your links: `div1` and `div2`.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TuEqL/2/)

```
$("a").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked "+$(this).html()) 
});
```

There are lots of ways to do this. Depending on what you want to display, you can always set an attribute of your links and then find that specific attribute using jQuery.

```
<a href="#div1" display="You clicked div 1!">Div 1</a>

$("a").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("display"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var bookmarkID;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
    bookmarkID = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
        console.log(bookmarkID);
    });
});
```

In this case you can get the last bookmark in the variable bookmarkID.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TuEqL/5/)